# Is there a way in c# to expand a call to multiple implementations of an interface implicitly?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Let's say I have two classes that both implement interface `Test`

```
public interface Test 
{
    void Write(string value);
}

public class Data1 : Test
{
    public void Write(string value) { Console.WriteLine(value); }
}
public class Data2 : Test
{
    public void Write(string value) { Console.WriteLine(value); }
}
```

Is there any way to use the interface to call multiple implementations of it?

For example, with the above code I want to do the following:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    private Data1 data1;
    private Data2 data2;

    // i'm aware this isn't code but this is the best way I had of describing it
    // basically my goal is to call both implementations with a single call
    public CallMethod(Test.Method, Parameters[]) 
    {
        data1.Method(Parameters); 
        data2.Method(Parameters);
    }
}
```

Its possible I'm going about this the wrong way but the whole goal of this is that I am in the process of migrating to a new database. I have two classes that both implement the same interface that write their data to their own database. I want to call both of those at the same time without having to explicitly write a wrapper method for each method. Eventually I will rip the old data class out and want to have as little code churn as possible.

Comment: Sorry, it works best when you have real code.  But trying to guess what you mean, are you saying you have interface IW that has a method, and you have classes D1 and D2 that implement IW.  You want to have a class Wrapper that holds references to instances of D1 and D2 and that also implements IW, and that that implementation calls the method of interest both of the D1 and D2 instances.  If that's your question, the answer is yes.

Comment: You could try an events based approach.

Comment: You could pass in a `Action<Test> action` and call it on each one `action(data1); action(data2);` and call it like `CallMethod(d => d.Write("SomeString"));`

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way how to do that. You have to have custom wrapper class/struct.